# Open Windows of Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

I went over the NSWorkspace doc and got this:

```
(NSRunningApplication *)currentApplication
```

But is there any way to find out how many (or if any) windows are currently open from that app ?

I know that there is some applescript to get it, but it is not permitted by the sandbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the CoreGraphics call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`.

You call it like this

```
    CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements, kCGNullWindowID);
```

and then iterate over the array of window information and do what you want with it.

I'm not sure how it's affected by sandboxing though.

Comment: Wow ! Thank you. Can anybody comment if it this can be still used in the sandbox ?